# Wireless bike computer will not enter sleep mode

Tags: electronics, computer

I have used a Raleigh wireless cycle computer for ages and no issues. I just recently replaced the battery in the sensor and now the bike computer will not enter sleep mode.  It is supposed to do so after 5 or 6 seconds.  Any ideas?  I've taken the batteries out a few times, put them back in and recalibrated it but to no effect.  It just won't turn off. Or should it just bin it for a better one?

Comment: Does it display speed correctly indicating that the wireless communication is working properly and the computer has proper contact to the antenna (usually integrated into the mount)? Is there maaaybe a setting for the sleep mode which got reset to “OFF” when you changed the battery? Is one of the buttons maybe stuck?

Comment: Hi Michael.  Yes it does display speed correctly although at one point it read 99km/h so my average and max numbers will be wrong.  It's supposed to just go out after 6 seconds.  Another odd thing is that it's now telling me that I am cycling forwards, but actually the computer is on my desk, nowhere near the bike.  Puzzled.

Comment: Maybe the computer has lost its connection with the sensor?   Is there a re-pairing process?

Comment: Could be interference from other wireless devices. Move it from your desk to somewhere away from things like cell phones and Wifi/bluetooth devices.

Comment: What frequency is the wireless link on?   What else is in the area transmitting on a similar frequency ?

Comment: Might be some good points here but the fact is that this computer seems to have a mind of its own both when on the bike, and nowhere near other devices, and also when on my desk.  It might just be quicker to bin it.  But first I'll try the things you and others suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

> Another odd thing is that it's now telling me that I am cycling forwards, but actually the computer is on my desk, nowhere near the bike. Puzzled.

Does it still have a connection to the sensor/transmitter? Kind of suggests that it is transmitting garbage. The sensor usually uses a reed switch to detect when the magnet on the wheel passes it. I guess it could be that the reed switch is wonky or halfway stuck. I’d try moving a strong magnet around the sensor in an attempt to un-stick it.